# wrong inch/dp values on some tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, units-of-measurement

My client wants a built-in ruler in his app to allow certain things to be measured without carrying around another tool. If I use ***in*** units when laying out the ruler, it works fine for most of my test devices. Android Studio warns me though that ***dp*** should be used instead of ***in***, because some devices will display inaccurately with the inch unit. When I test on my Amazon Fire 7 inch tablet, the hash marks are spaced out too much. My understanding is that 160dp should always equal 1 inch, so I try switching to 160dp and 320dp for my one inch and two inch hash marks, respectively. This time, the hash marks are too close together. See my screenshot below. The black marks are using inches; the red marks are using dp. The correct size lies *between* the black and the red marks.

How can I specify or convert to correct inch values on all devices? I'd prefer to specify all values in XML, but am perfectly willing to use Java code to adjust the layout as necessary. Also, is there a programmatic way to discover if inch units will be correct on a given device?

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one_inch_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ruler_hash_width"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="1in"
        android:background="@color/solid_black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/two_inch_left"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ruler_hash_width"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2in"
        android:background="@color/solid_black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/one_inch_left2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ruler_hash_width"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@color/red_button_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/two_inch_left2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/ruler_hash_width"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:background="@color/red_button_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any way to solve this with just XML; one `dp` is supposed to be **"approximately"** one pixel at 160dpi, but that isn't a hard guarantee.

However, the `DisplayMetrics` class includes the `xdpi` and `ydpi` fields, which will give you the device's real densities in each direction. You can then programmatically draw your ruler using these values.